# IISAdministration module - add web configuration

Tags: powershell, iis

I have below section in `applicationHost.config`:

```
<location path="MyWebSite/js">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Cache-Control" value="private,max-age=28800" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I can access it with below code:

```
$manager = Get-IISServerManager
$config = $manager.GetWebConfiguration("MyWebSite/js")
$headers = $config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpProtocol").GetCollection("customHeaders")
```

But how can I create this by using IISAdministration module?

I know I can do this with WebAdministration module, but we are trying to migrate old script to use new module, since it works faster.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Location "..." -Filter "..." ...
```

Comment: You just need to edit `$headers` from there, and then apply the changes to `$manager`. Then IISAdministration module should be smart enough to generate the section for you at the right place.

Comment: @LexLi in this case IISManager generates `web.config` inside `js` directory, but not as `<location>` in `applicationHost.config`. I know effect is the same, but why I cannot create new location in applicationHost.config

Comment: When saving changes, IIS internally uses a complex algorithm to decide where to put the tags (via location tags in applicationHost.config, or directly in web.config). If you use IIS Manager to configure the same setting, you will see it saves to web.config as well.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for help, I think I will accept the fact that config's will be stored in local web.config instead of applicationHost